# Can't bind to 'grid-columns' since it isn't a known property of 'grid-ui'

Tags: angular, typescript

grid-columns is showing error in app.Customer.html and in app.CustomerComponent.ts

app.Customer.html

```
<form [formGroup]="CustomerModel.formCustomerGroup">
Customer Code :<input formControlName="CustomerCodeControl" 
[(ngModel)]="CustomerModel.CustomerCode" type=text/><br>
Customer Name :<input formControlName="CustomerNameControl" 
 [(ngModel)]="CustomerModel.CustomerName" type=text/><br>
Customer Amount :<input [(ngModel)]="CustomerModel.CustomerAmount" 
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
type=text/><br>
<input [disabled]="!(CustomerModel.formCustomerGroup.valid)" (click)="Add()" type=button value="Add"/><br>
</form>
<div *ngIf="CustomerModel.formCustomerGroup.dirty"
            [hidden]="!(hasError('pattern','CustomerCodeControl'))" >Customer Code format is not proper</div><br>
<div *ngIf="CustomerModel.formCustomerGroup.dirty" 
            [hidden]="!(hasError('required','CustomerCodeControl'))" >Customer Code is required</div><br>
<div *ngIf="CustomerModel.formCustomerGroup.dirty"
            [hidden]="!(hasError('required','CustomerCodeControl'))" >Customer name is required</div><br>


<grid-ui [grid-columns]="[{'colName':'CustomerCode'},{'colName':'CustomerName'},{'colName':'CustomerAmount'}]"  
[grid-data]="CustomerModels"
(grid-selected)="SelectCustomer($event)"
></grid-ui>
```

app.CustomerComponent.ts

```
import { Component, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {Customer} from "./app.model";
import {BaseLogger} from "../Utility/app.Logger"
@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.CustomerView.html', 
})
export class CustomerComponent {
  title = 'MyApp';
  CustomerModel : Customer = new Customer();
  CustomerModels :Array<Customer>=new Array<Customer>();
  Logobj !: BaseLogger;
  constructor(_injector : Injector){
    this.Logobj = _injector.get("1");
    this.Logobj.Log;
  }
  SelectCustomer(_selected:Customer){
     this.CustomerModel = _selected;
  }
  Add(){
      this.CustomerModels.push(this.CustomerModel);
      this.CustomerModel=new Customer(); //clear UI
  }
  hasError(typeofvalidator:string,
        controlname:string) : boolean{
          return this.CustomerModel
                .formCustomerGroup
                .controls[controlname]
                .hasError(typeofvalidator);
  }
}
```

Can't bind to 'grid-columns' since it isn't a known property of 'grid-ui'.

1. If 'grid-ui' is an Angular component and it has 'grid-columns' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

2. If 'grid-ui' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.ngtsc(-998002)

app.CustomerComponent.ts(3, 55): Error occurs in the template of component CustomerComponent.

Comment: Any question do you have? [NgModule.schema docs ref](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#schemas)

Comment: It's Angular say you. If you are using a library, see that you import the **module** in the main.module.ts -or in the module where you're declaring your component-. If it's a component you create, see that the component is declares in the same module you're declare your component or is declared in a module and export and this module are declare in the module where you declare the component. NOTE: I can not find any library with "grid-ui" that work with Angular (don't confused with AngularJs).